# Why am I unable to retrieve commited new folder from svn with Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, svn, xcode4

I just started to use SVN with Xcode and stumbled upon several problems. I have started to work with SVN repository that was deployed on a remote server. The project had a standard directory structure (trunk, branches, tags). I have checked out the project with Xcode, did some work, performed commit (from Xcode). The teammate checked out that version. Then using Xcode, I have added new images folder and images to svn repository, and successfully performed commit. I ensure you that the image folder and the images were successfully uploaded to SVN server, because I saw that folder and images in trunk both from Xcode organizer and from browser, when was viewing the project remote files.

Now, my teammate performed update from Xcode (via file -> source -> update) but the image folder and images have not been retrieved. Xcode 4 just showed a message that a "project is up to date". He also went to organizer, then selected the trunk of repository and pressed update button, but the same message about project being up to date was shown. After more several tries, he deleted his local project files and performed checkout, but now the images were successfully retrieved. What might be a cause of such problem?

I know that for all required  tasks I might use svn terminal commands, just curious is it sufficient to use Xcode 4 without command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've had several issues with Xcode's SVN and have had to resort to the command line a few times to resolve them. Sometimes restarting Xcode has been enough, but if not here's a few simple svn commands that might help shed light on the issue, execute these from your project's root folder:

To check what state your SVN is in:

```
svn status
```

To update to most recent:

```
svn update
```

To commit:

```
svn commit -m "A commit message"
```

Comment: Thanks. Good to hear that I'm not the only one having problems with Xcode SVN :) I'm not a very big fan of using command line, always try to use one tool for one type of tasks. But it looks like it's not the case for Xcode SVN where I need to use both Xcode and command line :(

Comment: I tend to use either RapidSVN (at home) or Versions (at work) to do all my SVN activities. I also close Xcode while doing so such that it doesn't get in the way.